# negative prefixes vs not

Tags: prefixes

illogical
ineffective
impossible
irregular

I'd like to know if you agree that all these prefixes **can always be replaced by a construction with "not"**  -- so "not logical" etc **while having the same meaning**.

And **does "un" differ from the above prefixes** in that it often yields a stronger meaning  than "not", e.g. not happy can mean "neutral" and "unhappy" means "sad"

OR This person is unbelievable. (amazing, astonishing) This person is not believable. (not trustworthy)

Comment: For the first question, ***Not always***. Being ***indifferent*** to something certainly doesn't mean ***not different = same***. I'm sure there will be many more examples like that. And for ***un-***, consider ***uncanny***.

Comment: The _literal_ meaning of 'unbelievable' (and of 'not believable') is 'too strange to be readily believed'. Words like 'unbelievable, incredible, terrific' and so on are colloquial ways of saying 'very good'.

Comment: *Untied*, *unpacked*, etc, can mean formerly tied, packed, etc, but not any more, with verbs *untie*, *unpack*, while *not tied*, *not packed* don't have that meaning. This seems more like a word puzzle than a practical question though.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for the examples that you listed in your question. However, there are many exceptions where a word has a different meaning from what you might expect, and some examples  are in the comments. I would add **dis** to the list of prefixes for *not*, for example, dissatisfied (not satisfied). But disinterested means impartial, not uninterested.

I don't think you can say "always" when it comes to English grammar rules because, regardless of  the rule, there's probably an exception!

Comment: Your "disinterested" vs "uninterested" case is really interesting. Technically the OP's "not" substitution works for both of them, but each word operates on a different definition of "interested." It's a great case for keeping the pattern in mind as a guide, but treating each word as separate and looking it up in a dictionary.